# Content of div can't be retrieve

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to retrieve the content (image and title) of "`<div class="grid_6 alpha liste_img_lien">`" news page of "`http://www.lemonde.fr/`" to display it in web page. I saw many example that used simple html and I tried them but I couldn't achieve my goal please can someone help me to solve my problem.

```
<section class="global bord_rubrique bordt3 international international deroule_edito" data-vr-zone="international">
        <header>
        <div class="container container_18">
                <div class="grid_12 alpha">
                    <article class="img_tt_chapo" data-vr-contentbox="">
                    <div class="grid_6 alpha liste_img_lien">
                        <a data-vr-contentbox="" href="/international/visuel/2014/12/24/homs-la-ville-trophee-d-assad_4545940_3210.html">
                        <a data-vr-contentbox="" href="/international/article/2014/12/26/en-cote-d-ivoire-les-espoirs-decus-pour-une-justice-equitable_4546381_3210.html">
                        <a data-vr-contentbox="" href="/europe/article/2014/12/25/turquie-un-adolescent-de-16-ans-passible-de-4-ans-de-prison-pour-insulte-a-erdogan_4546085_3214.html">
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_6 omega liste_img_lien">
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_6 omega txt3_120 col_droite">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <p class="grid_18 lien_chaine">
</section>
```

this is the code that I used

```
<?php

require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html =new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file("http://www.lemonde.fr/");

foreach($html->find('div[class="grid_6 alpha liste_img_lien]') as $element){
    echo $element;

}

?>
```

Comment: the correct CSS selector would be `div.grid_6.alpha.liste_img_lien` but I'm not sure if the simple html dom library support that, you would have to try: `$html->find('div.grid_6.alpha.liste_img_lien')`.

Comment: @hakre - simple doesn't support that but [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) does.

Comment: @pguardiario: nice. take care you're library isn't prone to xpath injection as you process some input there unsafely: [Mitigating XPath Injection Attacks in PHP](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/mitigating-xpath-injection-attacks-in-php/)